# Compact subsets of convex sets

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $(X,\|\cdot\|)$ be a Banach space, and $\{x_{n}\}$ a sequence in $X$ with $\|x_{n}\|=1$ for every $n\geq 1$. Now, let $B$ the convex hull of the sequence $\{x_{n}\}$ and $K\subset B$ compact.

For each integer $n$, let $R_{n}:B\longrightarrow X$ be the mapping defined as  $R_{n}(x):=\sum_{j\geq n}\lambda_{j}x_{j}$ for all $x:=\sum_{j\geq 1}\lambda_{j}x_{j}\in B$, with $\lambda_{j}\geq 0$ and $\sum_{j\geq 1}\lambda _{j}=1$. Can we infer that the following assert?

$$
(*)  \quad \lim_{n} \sup_{x\in K} \|R_{n}(x)\|=0
$$

I have tried the following: by the compactness of $K$, given any $\varepsilon >0$, there are $k_{1},\ldots, k_{m}\in K$ such that $K\subset \cup_{i=1}^{m} B(k_{i},\varepsilon)$ (the closed ball centered at $k_{i}$ and radius $\varepsilon$).

Then, given $x\in K$, put $x:=\sum_{j\geq 1}\mu_{j}x_{j}$, $\mu_{j}\geq 0$ and $\sum_{j\geq 1}\mu_{j}=1$, taking $i$ such that $\|x-k_{i}\|\leq \varepsilon$, $k_{i}:=\sum_{j\geq 1} \lambda_{ij}x_{j}$, we have

$$
\|\sum_{j\geq N-1}\mu_{j}x_{j}\|\leq \  \| \sum_{j\geq 1}\mu_{j}x_{j} -k_{i}\|+ \|k_{i}-\sum_{j=1}^{N-1}\lambda_{ij}x_{j}\| + \|\sum_{j=1}^{N-1}\lambda_{ij}x_{j}-\sum_{j=1}^{N-1}\mu_{j}x_{j}\| \leq 2\varepsilon + 
$$
$$
\|\sum_{j=1}^{N-1}\lambda_{ij}x_{j}-\sum_{j=1}^{N-1}\mu_{j}x_{j}\|,
$$ 
for enough large $N$, but I do not know how to continue...Some suggestions? Here, I think that the last above right-hand side is, by the compactness of $K$, "uniformly" bounded, It is true?

Maybe the result holds by considering the conitnuous function $\|R_{n}(x)\|$ defined on the compact $K$ (and therefore attains its supremum)??

Many thanks in advance for your comments.

Answer (score 1):

I tried a different approach. Let $x\in K$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $$ ||R_{n}(x)|| = ||\sum_{j \geq n} \lambda_{j}x_{j} || \leq\sum_{j \geq n}|\lambda_{j}|||x_{j}|| = \sum_{j\geq n}\lambda_{j}$$ Given that the series $\sum_{j} \lambda_{j}$ is convergent (equal to $1$), we have that $$ \lim_{n } \sum_{j \geq n} \lambda_{j} = 0 $$ Thus taking the supremum on in the first inequality we get $$\lim_{n} \sup_{x\in K}||R_{n}(x)|| = 0$$
NB: If the above reasoning is correct, I don't understand why $K$ has to be compact here, so I may be mistaken.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I feel that the compactness is essential. Think, for instance, in the closed unit ball of $c_{0}$.

Comment: You mean the closed unit ball of the set of continuous functions?

Comment: Or any space Banach space of infinite dimension....